# Extract all divs containing specific keywords using XPath/HTML Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html, xml, dom, xpath

I try to extract data from an html(-->xml)-document (below) using the HTML Agility Pack. The "`div`"s that contain "`id=dealId_*****`"  are relevant. I think I know how to proceed, when I figure out how to just count all "`div`"s with "`id=dealId_*****`". I tried using the XPath-Method "`starts-with`", but it didn't work:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(Sourcecode);

int numberOfDIVs;
numberOfDIVs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='jLocalDeals']/*[starts-with(@id, 'dealId_']").Count;

    <div id="jLocalDeals" class="dealsBlock" style="">
    <h1>
    <div id="dealId_5474417" class="jDeal LEISURE_OFFERS">
    <div id="dealId_5476688" class="jDeal SHOPPING">
    <div id="dealId_5445019" class="jDeal TICKETS1 RESTAURANT1">
    <div class="wrapper3Deals"></div>
    <div id="dealId_5474286" class="jDeal BEAUTY">
    <div id="dealId_5476685" class="jDeal LEISURE_OFFERS">
    <div id="dealId_5474466" class="jDeal SERVICES">
    <div class="wrapper3Deals"></div>
    <div id="dealId_5466810" class="jDeal BEAUTY">
    <div id="dealId_5425417" class="jDeal SERVICES">
    <div id="dealId_5474329" class="jDeal SHOPPING">
    <div class="wrapper3Deals"></div>
    <div id="dealId_5476703" class="jDeal SHOPPING">
    <div id="dealId_5476729" class="jDeal SHOPPING">
    <div id="dealId_5474702" class="jDeal HEALTHCARE">
    <div class="wrapper3Deals"></div>
    <div id="dealId_5444044" class="jDeal TRAVEL1" style="display: block;">
    <div id="dealId_5474444" class="jDeal LEISURE_OFFERS" style="display: block;">
    <div id="dealId_5473774" class="jDeal TRAVEL1" style="display: block;">
    <div class="wrapper3Deals"></div>
    </div>
```

P.S.: Unfortunately I am only able to use .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Use the contains() function:

```
//div[@id='jLocalDeals']//div[contains(@id,'dealId')]
```

If you want a shortcut, you could use the count() function within the xpath:

```
count(//div[@id='jLocalDeals']//div[contains(@id,'dealId')])
```

Also, the reason starts-with didn't work in your xpath is because you're checking the ids for the children of `//div[@id='jLocalDeals']`, not the children of `<h1>` which is where the `<div id="dealId_****"/>` are. Using starts-with:

```
//div[@id='jLocalDeals']//div[starts-with(@id,'dealId')]
```

Or

```
//div[@id='jLocalDeals']/*/*[starts-with(@id,'dealId')]
```

Hope this helps, and let me know if I need to clarify anything...

Comment: Thanks, but that also doesn't work (NullReferenceException) :( This is the webpage, I am trying to scrape: http://www.groupon.de/alle-deals/aachen. What do you mean with >use count() within the path?

Comment: There's an XPath function count() which returns the number of nodes. Not any different than using HtmlDocument.Count(), just pointing it out so you'd know. Are you getting anything back when you run simply //div[@id='jLocalDeals']?

Comment: By simply running //div[@id='jLocalDeals'] I get back NumberofDIVs=1  [And this](http://www.imgbox.de/users/public/images/1dMjr3WXhI.JPG). I hope you can help me out.

Comment: Sorry can't view imgbox, it's blocked where I am. Could you load that to imgur?

Comment: Ok, I can't really discern much from that, but I do see it is finding only 4 nodes but your original post has at least 15. The XPath I posted above worked for the xml you have in your original post, so post all the reference info you can in the question and I'll look some more, but I don't think it's the xpath if the above isn't working.

Comment: I tested "starts-with" now with other websites, and it worked as expected. So it has something to do with the HTML of http://www.groupon.de/alle-deals/aachen. I found out something (using Firefox->Firebug), that might be interesting: If you analyze the Link "Alle Angebote in Aachen" (wich means "All offers in the city of Aachen"). You **don't** get a href link, but instead a _linkfor="jLocalDeals"_ ?? Maybe my program never reaches the document that I can see using Firebug?

Comment: I do see that in the groupon page's source you posted, so just change your XPath to reflect whatever naming scheme they use and try it out. I'll do the same and edit my answer with any findings..

Comment: I don't know if I understood you right. What I did now is trying it using the absolut XPath of "//*[@id='jLocalDeals']": "/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[9]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]". But this also does not work... what's wrong with that?